# Show gradient as image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to run a code which should show the result as a figure in MATLAB.  The image is supposed to be 512 x 512.  All of the rows in the first column are zeroes and they change to 255 by reaching 512th column.  However, all I am getting is a few black columns followed by white columns.  I can't see where the mistake is! I am attaching my code.

```
clear all;

r=512;
c=512;

a=zeros(r,c);

for i=3:c
    b=round((i-2)/2);

    a(:,i)=b;

end

cast(a,'uint8');
imshow(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively easy fix: you forgot to set your `cast` to `a`. Now you're ploting doubles instead of uint32.

```
r=512;
c=512;

a=zeros(r,c);

for i=3:c
    b=round((i-2)/2);

    a(:,i)=b;

end

a = uint8(a);
imshow(a);
```

Comment: I also used uint8 instead of cast, since it's slightly faster.